# is it possible to export azure billing report to a database for detailed analysis?

Tags: azure, azure-billing

is it possible to export azure billing report to a database for detailed analysis?
I know storage export but csv doesn't help. something like gcp billing export to bigquery exists for azure?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a billing support question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know there is no direct export capability to a database in azure billing.

We export to a storage account and then use Databricks to read in the CSV and perform some analytics as well as load it into our data warehouse.